# Explicit type hint in method reference lambda results in raw type

Tags: java, types, jvm

Mapping an Optional with an explicitly typed generic method reference seem to cause type inference to fail in some cases. In the following example the first line compiles whereas when giving the `List::of`-method an explicit type with `List::<String>of` it does not compile:

```
Optional.of("one,two").map(List::of).get().get(0).split(",");
// No problem, type inference works fine

Optional.of("one,two").map(List::<String>of).get().get(0).split(",");
// Compiler error, because the mapped Optional becomes typed with a raw List parameter (Optional<List>)
```

In the above case the type hint to List::of was unnecessary, but there are many cases where it is needed and to help the compiler one has to type hint the map, resulting in the much more verbose

```
Optional.of("one,two").<List<String>>map(List::of).get().get(0).split(",");
```

One case would be if we had some Either type like

```
static class Either<L, R> {
  L left;
  R right;

  private Either(final L left, final R right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }

  static <L, R> Either<L, R> left(final L l) {
    return new Either<>(l, null);
  }

  static <L, R> Either<L, R> right(final R r) {
    return new Either<>(null, r);
  }
}
```

then

```
final String right =
    Optional.of("one,two")
        .map(Either::<String, String>left)
        .orElse(Either.right("three,four"))
        .right;
```

fails to compile, instead one has to do

```
final String right =
    Optional.of("one,two")
        .<Either<String, String>>map(Either::left)
        .orElse(Either.right("three,four"))
        .right;
```

Why is it so and are there any plans to change this?

**Update:**

I am using OpenJDK 15, but this seems to be a problem in Intellij - running javac from the command-line all of this compiles, but Intellij erroneously highlights some of the above lines as compile errors. I will close and report a bug.

Comment: Can you show such a case where type hint needed?

Comment: @Eklavya I added a case to the question - although contrived, a more realistic use case could be imagined if we know less about the Optional we map on.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  All of your code compiles for me.

Comment: @VGR You're right. I'm using OpenJDK 15 but it turns out that it is Intellij that highlights these problems (using the same JDK), because command-line it works fine. I guess I have to close the question and report a bug to Jetbrains instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Intellij.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252839